# I want to hide and create a folder. But it doesn't create a folder

Tags: batch-file

I want to make a little File/Folder Hide/Unhide batch program. So I want to make a hidden folder the folder creating code looks like that:

```
set setupPath="C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\FiFoH"
IF NOT EXIST %setupPath% (
cd "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop"
mkdir FiFoH
attrib +S +H %setupPath%
cd %setupPath%
echo. >> log.txt
)
```

But it doesn't create a folder.

Comment: You're creating a folder and then marking it as a hidden system folder, which would require you to uncheck two boxes in preferences in order to view. Are you sure you just can't see it?

Comment: There is *no* guarantee that a user's profile is located under `C:\Users`. Prefer to use `%UserProfile%` rather than `C:\Users\%username%`

Comment: What makes you think your procedure does not work? Try `dir /ah %setuppath%` which should show you the directory, or `dir  %setuppath%\*.*` which should show you the file. Remember - the procedure is only going to take place if `%setuppath%"` does not exist...

Comment: Yes , setuped that I can see hidden folders and system folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is in cd "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop" and cd %setupPath%. The cd command will not accept full paths unless you use the /D switch.
The following code should work:

```
set setupPath="%userprofile%\Desktop\FiFoH"
IF NOT EXIST %setupPath% (
cd /D "%userprofile%\Desktop"
mkdir FiFoH
attrib +S +H %setupPath%
cd /D %setupPath%
echo. >> log.txt
)
```

Also, you don't need to use the %username% variable and can go a more direct route to your desktop folder by using %userprofile% to get to the user profile (which in your case would be C:\Users\%username%).